# NODEJS Count all array number

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanna get number of total array in NodeJS. Any way can do this?

For example: In picture have array from 0 > 558. Then I want a function to give the count is 559

Thank you.

Hieu

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `array.length`?

Comment: Did you try using your favorite search engine for something like "get array size in javascript"?

Comment: What is displayed in this image is the indices of your array, which in most languages start at 0. Using ```array.length``` with give you 559 as expected.

Comment: @David im not good in english, then don't know explain my mind for google ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is only broken in console since it is very long: (i.e: if the length of array is longer than 100 then the console will break it to show it clearly..).  if u logged the length then it will show 559, just do arr.length